# Протокол поверх TCP, язык C, Windows

Tags: c, windows, tcp

Возникла потребность организовать определенный протокол поверх TCP, который работает по принципу:

1) Сторона А отправляет данные стороне Б (int, char, double, не суть важно);

2) Сторона А ожидает 1 байт - подтверждение, что данные приняты и обработаны на стороне Б, а не валяются во внутреннем буфере системы на стороне А (или даже на стороне Б).

Проблема в том, что сторона Б может нарушить логическую согласованность действий, например с целью обрушения стороны А.

Сторона Б в ответ на пришедшие данные может отправить не 1 байт с подтверждением, а два, или больше. Или даже отправить один байт сразу, а где-то после получения байта на стороне А, но до отправки следующих данных на стороне А, отправить еще.

Таким образом будет рассогласование, и я не понимаю, как его проконтролировать на стороне А.

В целях упрощения можно считать, что А шлет данные, а Б шлет подтверждения, что это односторонний канал посылки данных.

Например, как эта проблема решается в таких протоколах, как SIP? Как контролируется, что пришел ответ именно "ACK", а не "ACK^53"?

Надеюсь, мне удалось описать суть проблемы достаточно ясно.

Comment: Можно ожидать не просто один байт, а какой-то ID (например, crc32 отправленного стороной A сообщения).

Comment: Я понимаю. Большинство протоколов вообще работают поверх TCP в текстовом режиме, тот же SIP, например. Но это проблемы не решит. Придет нам в ответ "OK" или даже "OK" + хэш-сумма принятых данных... В буфере может оказаться еще что-то. Как это что-то проконтролировать?

Comment: Как только сторона А видит, что в буфере мусор или что-то лишнее, она должна сообщить стороне Б об ошибке и закрыть соединение, не дожидаясь более никаких подтверждений.

Comment: То есть, так обычно и делается? А я думал, что это мой велосипед, и есть более правильное решение. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строгое решение проблемы:

1. В заголовок протокола, который Вы накладываете на TCP, добавляете два поля: ID сообщения и CRC32
2. Отправляющая сторона, после передачи пакета данных, заносит его ID, CRC32 и время отправки пакета в список отправленных сообщений
3. Принимающая сторона, получив пакет с данными, данные оставляет у себя, а заголовок с ID и CRC32 отправляет обратно
4. Отправитель, получив подтверждение, вычёркивает этот пакет из списка отправленных.
5. Заодно, отправитель проверяет, нет ли в списке отправленных пакетов, на которых не пришло подтверждение по истечению таймаута. Такие пакеты передаются повторно.

Comment: Я так и делаю, но проблема чуть в другом: как контролировать размер пришедших данных?

Допустим, мы отправили данные и ждем подтверждение, допустим размер подтверждения 100 байт. Ждем, не важно, как - блокирующим recv(...,...,100,...); или select() в цикле + recv(), пока не придут ожидаемые 100 байт. После того, как мы получили 100 байт - в приемном буфере могут остаться какие-то данные, которых при правильном обмене там быть не должно. И поэтому при следующей отправке данных и ожидании ответа эти данные окажут влияние.

Comment: **в приемном буфере могут остаться какие-то данные** Если у Вас *select* стоит в цикле, то забрав свои 100 байт, Вы возвращаетесь на *select* и обнаруживаете, что в приёмном сокете есть данные. Какие тут могут быть проблемы - я не очень понимаю...

Comment: Проблема в том, что оставшиеся в приемном буфере данные могут как минимум мешать при обработке следующего подтверждения. Как максимум - дыры в логике протокола. В моем случае это, бесспорно, к большим проблемам не приведет, потому что логика очень простая. Но если логика протокола более-менее сложная, как, например, у протокола SIP, то очень тяжело предсказать, что будет, если вторая сторона умышленно начнет присылать не то, что ожидается. Вот я и пытаюсь понять, как эту проблему решить.

Comment: Т.е. на самом деле, вас интересует как ОТДЕЛИТЬ одно сообщение от другого. Ну тут есть только два стандартных метода:

1. Сообщения точно определённой длины, как в UDP. Там драйвер Вам скажет реальную длину сообщения.


2. Использовать символ-разделитель сообщений. Например - две пустые строки.